# A function to measure time of overloaded operators and member function

Tags: c++

**Description**

---

Is it possible to write a function that can be used to measure the time of operators as well as other functions something like this:

```
// pass an operator as an argument
measureTime(MyClass::operator*, lhs, rhs);

// Pass a function as an argument
measureTime(MyFunction(arg1, arg2));

// or
measureTime(MyFunction, arg1, arg2);

// or other signatures ...
```

I came across a function template to do this:

```
template<typename F, typename... Args>
double measureTime(F func, Args&&... args){
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return high_resolution_clock::now() - t1;
}
```

Not sure how to use this (or write a new function) to measure the time of overloaded operators.

**Questions**

---

- What is the best way to do this (if possible)?
- If not possible, what are the other options ?

**Example**

---

*I'm writing a library for big integer arithmetic, I am using different algorithms and want to measure (and compare) their times (and see their behaviour) when passing different length integers...*

This is part of my class:

```
class bigint {
   public:
      int compare(const bigint& other) const;
      bigint operator*(const bigint& rhs) const;
      bigint& operator++();
      bigint otherAlgorithms(const bigint& other) const;
      // and more ...
}
```

I also have a lot of input data, and want to pass those data within a `for` loop and print out the times.

*That's why I was looking for a generic function that can printout the times for any function / operator.*

Comment: If you use `std::invoke` instead of calling the function yourself this should work with member functions-

Comment: Unless `MyFunc` returns a function, passing `MyFunction(arg1, arg2)` will pass the result of the expression

Comment: An operator is still a function, so there should be no problem passing it. Something like `operator<<(a, b)`

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Give some really concrete use cases and I'm sure you'll get a really concrete answer :-)

Comment: @AndyG I am working on a class to implement Big Integer arithmetic and other math operations, I wan a generic function that I can pass all operators/member functions to measure their time. (basically unit testing with a lot of input data)

Comment: @AliSharabiani there are benchmark-libraries to help you with that. Calling a function _once_ won't give you useful measurements.

Answer (score 7):

`std::invoke` can invoke functions, lambdas and member-functions, so let `std::invoke` handle the function call:

```
template<typename... Args>
double measureTime(Args&&... args){
    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::invoke(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return duration(high_resolution_clock::now() - t1);
}
```

Now you can measure member functions and operators:

```
struct Test {
    void aFunction() {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n";  
    }

    void operator++() {
        std::cout << "Hello World\n"; 
    }
};
int main()
{
    Test t;
    std::cout << measureTime(&Test::aFunction, t) << "\n";
    std::cout << measureTime(&Test::operator++, t) << "\n";
}
```

[Working Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15dc8a138dec11b3)

Edit: 
Even though I don't recommend using it, it does look nice:

```
 #define MEASURE(call) measureTime([&](){ call; })
 std::cout << MEASURE(t.aFunction()) << "\n";
```

And it allows you to measure more than one function call.

```
std::cout << MEASURE(t.aFunction(); t.aFunction(); t.aFunction();) << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. To be more specific, this is the signature of my operator: `bigint operator*(const bigint& rhs) const`. (it has arguments).

Comment: You can pass the arguments after the function and the class instance, i.e. `measureTime(&bigint::operator*, bigint1, bigint2);` where `bigint1` is the instance the member is called on (its the `this` inside the function) and `bigint2` is the parameter.